# google maps v3 infobox not loading

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infobox

Sorry i know this has been covered soo many times but no matter what answer i find it never seems to work for me.

Basically, i cant get an info box to load on click....and each time i use the code to create and load an info box it seems to prevent my markers loading.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library- v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
var markers = [];
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.899114,-1.730348);

    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
    boxText.innerHTML = "City Hall, Sechelt<br>British Columbia<br>Canada";

    var boxOptions = {
             content: boxText
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: { 
              background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
              ,opacity: 0.75
              ,width: "280px"
             }
            ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
    };
    var infobox= new InfoBox();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        //scrollwheel: false,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);
    addPostCode('POSTCODE');
    addPostCode('POSTCODE');
addPostCode('POSTCODE');

}

function addPostCode(zip) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {
        var iconBase = 'http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/images/';
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        url:'http://www.google.com',
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        name: zip,
        icon: iconBase + 'icon.png'
        //shadow: iconBase + 'schools_maps.shadow.png'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //window.location.href = marker.url;
        infobox.setContent('test');
        infobox.open(map, marker);
        });
    markers.push(marker);
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
    });
}

function checkZip(zip)
{
    var distance = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var index = 0;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            for(ix=0; ix< markers.length; ix++)
            {
                var tmp = getDistance(results[0].geometry.location, markers[ix].position);
                if (tmp < distance)
                {
                    distance = tmp;
                    index = ix;
                }
            }
            alert('nearest zipcode is :' + markers[index].name);
        }
    });
}

function getDistance(latlng1, latlng2)
{
    var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    var dLat = (latlng2.lat()-latlng1.lat()) * Math.PI / 180;  // Javascript functions in radians
    var dLon = (latlng2.lng()-latlng1.lng()) * Math.PI / 180;
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(latlng1.lat()  * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(latlng2.lat()  * Math.PI / 180) *
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    d = d * 0.621371192;
    return d;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just quickly skimming through the code I notice that `infobox` is being called in your `addPostCode()` function when `infobox` is not declared as a global variable (it's local to your `initialize()` function).

Comment: Hi, i've found the problem, the infobox= new InfoBox(); was being called outside of the loop for each marker, i've moved it inside the addPostcode function and its all fine....i just put it there as thats what all the other examples did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the error "InfoBox is undefined".  Because there is a typo in your post (is it in your real code).

Then I see markers (obviously not your custom ones, as you didn't provide the correct URL).

If I click on a marker, I get an error: `Error: 'infobox' is undefined`.

If I fix that by moving the declaration of the "infobox" variable to the global scope, it works with no errors, but there is no content for the infoboxes...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
var markers = [];
var infobox= new InfoBox();
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.899114,-1.730348);

    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
    boxText.innerHTML = "City Hall, Sechelt<br>British Columbia<br>Canada";

    var boxOptions = {
             content: boxText
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: { 
              background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
              ,opacity: 0.75
              ,width: "280px"
             }
            ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
    };
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        //scrollwheel: false,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);
    addPostCode('POSTCODE');
    addPostCode('POSTCODE');
addPostCode('POSTCODE');

}

function addPostCode(zip) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {
        var iconBase = 'http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/images/';
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        url:'http://www.google.com',
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        name: zip /*,
        icon: iconBase + 'icon.png' */
        //shadow: iconBase + 'schools_maps.shadow.png'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //window.location.href = marker.url;
        infobox.setContent('test');
        infobox.open(map, marker);
        });
    markers.push(marker);
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
    });
}

</script>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_InfoBoxMarkers.html)